# Android: The code in my Broadcast Receiver is repeatedly executing

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, phone-state-listener

Hai iam new to android development working with the broadcast receivers for the first time...My app has a broadcast receiver and a class(**MyPhoneStateListener.java**) which extends **PhoneStateListener** to notify the phone number of the incoming call. Here the issue is i have a Log.d("no", msg) statement in MyPhoneStateListener.java to view the incoming call number in logcat. When i launch my app for the first time and test it, the phone number is shown once that is fine, when i test it for second time the phone number is shown three times(the statement or the class may be executed 3 times),and when i test it again the phone number is shown 5 times and so on...i posted my codes below please check it and help me to solve.

BroadReceiver.java

```
package com.vibrator;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
//import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.PhoneStateListener;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
import android.util.Log;
//import android.widget.Toast;

public class BroadReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{



        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        try {
                   // TELEPHONY MANAGER class object to register one listner
                    TelephonyManager tmgr = (TelephonyManager) context
                            .getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

                    //Create Listner
                    MyPhoneStateListener PhoneListener = new MyPhoneStateListener();

                    // Register listener for LISTEN_CALL_STATE
                    tmgr.listen(PhoneListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("Phone Receive Error", " " + e);
            }
        }
```

MyPhoneStateListener.java

```
package com.vibrator;
import android.telephony.PhoneStateListener;
import android.util.Log;

    public class MyPhoneStateListener extends PhoneStateListener {

            public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {

               // Log.d("MyPhoneListener",state+"   incoming no:"+incomingNumber);
               //if the call state is ringing(i.e state=1) then if statements executes
                if (state == 1) {

                    String msg = "New Phone Call Event. Incomming Number : "+incomingNumber;
                    Log.d("no", msg);

                }
            }
        }


    }
```

Logcat:

```
08-03 12:24:15.258: D/dalvikvm(5878): VFY: replacing opcode 0x70 at 0x0000
08-03 12:24:15.268: D/dalvikvm(5878): VFY: dead code 0x0003-0007 in Landroid/support/v7/internal/view/menu/ActionMenuView$LayoutParams;.<init> (Landroid/support/v7/internal/view/menu/ActionMenuView$LayoutParams;)V
08-03 12:24:54.618: D/no(5878): New Phone Call Event. Incomming Number : 0123456789
08-03 12:24:54.797: D/onpause(5878): onpause mainactivity
08-03 12:25:14.797: D/no(5878): New Phone Call Event. Incomming Number : 0123456789
08-03 12:25:14.797: D/no(5878): New Phone Call Event. Incomming Number : 0123456789
08-03 12:25:14.857: D/no(5878): New Phone Call Event. Incomming Number : 0123456789
08-03 12:25:15.137: D/onpause(5878): onpause mainactivity
08-03 12:25:21.417: D/dalvikvm(5878): GC_EXPLICIT freed 2421 objects / 175800 bytes in 443ms
08-03 12:25:27.629: D/no(5878): New Phone Call Event. Incomming Number : 0123456789
08-03 12:25:27.629: D/no(5878): New Phone Call Event. Incomming Number : 0123456789
08-03 12:25:27.638: D/no(5878): New Phone Call Event. Incomming Number : 0123456789
08-03 12:25:27.658: D/no(5878): New Phone Call Event. Incomming Number : 0123456789
08-03 12:25:27.738: D/no(5878): New Phone Call Event. Incomming Number : 0123456789
08-03 12:25:28.027: D/onpause(5878): onpause mainactivity
08-03 12:25:36.617: D/no(5878): New Phone Call Event. Incomming Number : 0123456789
08-03 12:25:36.617: D/no(5878): New Phone Call Event. Incomming Number : 0123456789
08-03 12:25:36.627: D/no(5878): New Phone Call Event. Incomming Number : 0123456789
08-03 12:25:36.637: D/no(5878): New Phone Call Event. Incomming Number : 0123456789
08-03 12:25:36.637: D/no(5878): New Phone Call Event. Incomming Number : 0123456789
08-03 12:25:36.647: D/no(5878): New Phone Call Event. Incomming Number : 0123456789
08-03 12:25:36.727: D/no(5878): New Phone Call Event. Incomming Number : 0123456789
08-03 12:25:37.127: D/onpause(5878): onpause mainactivity
```

Comment: How ever my problem is solved...here is the [**link**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22504869/using-broadcastreceiver-with-functionality-of-phonestatelistener) might be helpful to someone